# Trying to sum MODIS ET data by each month

Tags: modis

I am currently evaluating water resource availability over the Bahamas using GEE (I'm new to this) and am running into some trouble. I am trying to sum the ET over the Bahamas for each month from MODIS and am getting some odd numbers. I want to make clear, I need the sum from each month in the time frame. I have done this for precipitation, but the numbers do not appear to be as "off" as the ET values. Below is my code:

```js
//SETUP DATES
var startYear = 2001;
var endYear = 2019;
var startDate=ee.Date.fromYMD(startYear,01,01);
var endDate=ee.Date.fromYMD(endYear+1,12,31);
var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);
//SET REGION
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB/2013").filter(ee.Filter.inList('name', ['THE BAHAMAS']));
var region = dataset
var styling = {color: 'red', fillColor: '00000000'};
Map.addLayer(region.style(styling))

//SET VARIABLES
var sst = ee.Image('NOAA/AVHRR_Pathfinder_V52_L3/20120802025048').select('sea_surface_temperature')
  .rename('sst')
  .divide(100);
var P = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY").select('precipitation')
            .filterDate(startDate, endDate);
var ET = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD16A2').filterDate(startDate, endDate).select(['ET']); 


//MONTH
//ET
var nMonths = ee.Number(endDate.difference(startDate,'month')).round();
var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0,nMonths).map(function (n) {
    var ini = startDate.advance(n,'month');
    var end = ini.advance(1,'month');
    return ET.filterDate(ini,end)
                .select(0).sum()
                .set('system:time_start', ini);
}));

print(byMonth);

Map.addLayer(ee.Image(byMonth.first()),{min: 15, max: 35},'ET');

// plot full time series
print(
  ui.Chart.image.series({
    imageCollection: byMonth,
    region: region,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 1000
  }).setOptions({title: 'ET over time'})
);
```

I'm getting something like 200 mm of ET in a month....that can't be correct. That results in close to 3000 mm of ET in a year, and based on precipitation, that's impossible. I am trying to figure out if there is a calculation I am missing or something in the ET product I am unaware of. I have tried returning ET as a sum and a mean (see `ET.filterDate(ini,end).select(0).sum()`) and get not so great values for both. Am I missing something regarding what MODIS is giving me? The units are in kg/m2/8days which is mmH2O/8 days.

Answer (score 0):

You have not applied the scale factor. Read the ET band description of the MODIS data.

```
var modET = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD16A2').filterDate(startDate, endDate); 

//Apply Scale factor on ET Band= 0.1
var ET = modET.map(function(img) {
  return img.select('ET').multiply(0.1).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});
```